# What is the definition of the decompositon of $\mathbb{C}^n$ into isotypical components?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I consider a normal subgroup $H^0 \subset H$ (the connected component of the identity). And $H$ acting irreducible on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Then i have a question about the definition of

---

*the decomposition of $\mathbb{C}^n$ into isotypical components for $H^0$.*

---

I just can´t make sense of that phrase. I take it, that this is some kind of decomposition $V=\mathbb{C}^n = V_1 \oplus ... \oplus V_d$ into subspaces. Well, i have an irreducible representation $\rho: H \to GL(V)$ which i can restrict to $H^0$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the basics of representation theory?

Comment: Yes, but just the basics.

Comment: Did you try googling it? This is the second result I get: https://pabloocal.github.io/FSWAG2020/ByeongsuYu_SWAGnotes_20201013.pdf